# Php redirect to two pages at the same time

Tags: php

I'm novice in php and i wonder how can i accomplish to redirect from one site to two sites.

These sites must be openned in two separates tabs in the browser. One page is the main one and the other is the Help page. I want such pages be opppened at the same time.

Is it possible? Is there any trick to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Impossible from PHP, but can be done from JS.
check out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: A PHP script can not do that.  Instead your web page can load another window/tab using JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot do that with a server redirect. You either have to click a link to open a new tab, or do it via Javascript.

Comment: You should not do that: The browser will most likely block a non-user-initiated pop-up and it is extremely annoying...

Comment: What's wrong with the old-fashioned 'Help' button? You can open a new window/tab by setting the `target` attribute of the link to `_blank`. This way the help window/tab is only opened when needed.